# Is there a polynomial time algorithm for finding primes?

Tags: prime-numbers, algorithms, computational-complexity, computational-number-theory

I was wondering if, given $k$, there is a deterministic polynomial time algorithm (polynomial in $k$) which finds a prime number with $k$ digits.

There is clearly a probabilistic one: just take random numbers and apply (probabilistic or deterministic) primality test. Also, if one assumes some strong conjectures on the distribution of primes, like Cramer's conjecture, for instance, then one can test primality of roughly $k^2$ consecutive numbers, each in polynomial time, and find a prime.

But is there a deterministic algorithm which provably works? Or maybe the one which works conditioned on weaker conjectures than Cramer's conjecture?

Comment: It's possible to double the size of a prime using [Pocklington primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pocklington_primality_test). However, while this works well in practice, theoretic bounds for the running time of this method are not optimistic, and best ones depend on ERH. Here is a [discussion in Russian](http://nature.web.ru/db/msg.html?mid=1157083&uri=node33.html) from Yaschenko et al. *Introduction to Cryptography* book.

Comment: The method seems to originate from the paper: Plaisted D. A. [Fast verification, testing, and generation of large primes](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0304397579900021/pdf) // *Theor. Comp. Sci.* 9 (1979): 1-16.

Comment: This is open; see [Polymath4](https://asone.ai/polymath/index.php?title=Finding_primes) and [Pseudodeterministic Constructions in Subexponential Time](https://eccc.weizmann.ac.il/report/2016/196/) for partial results.

Comment: @sdcvvc Thanks for the links! Judging by the Polymath4 discussions, even finding deterministically such a prime faster than in time $10^{k/2}$ is open. Which is really quite surprising to me.

Answer (score 2):

A recent [paper](https://eccc.weizmann.ac.il/report/2023/076/) made some progress on this problem and gave a pseudodeterministic algorithm. Looks like it has been peer-reviewed and will appear in [FOCS 2023](https://focs.computer.org/2023/focs-2023-list-of-accepted-papers/).

As was pointed out in the comments, pseudodeterministic ≠ deterministic.

Comment: While this is an important result, pseudodeterministic $\ne$ deterministic, so it does *not* answer the original question in the affirmative.

Comment: From the abstract it also seems like it is only guaranteed to work for infinitely inputs, not all. Correct me if I'm wrong but I think this means it's not technically a pseudodeterministic solution to the problem?